# Adding an alternative title to an existing thread

Tags: discussion, search, title

How can I make an existing thread easier to find using certain keywords?

For example, today I had a question, "When does LASSO fail?". I searched this on Cross Validated and could not find an answer. However, with some effort I located a thread called "When wouldn't I use LASSO for model selection?" which essentially addresses the same question.

I would like to add "When does LASSO fail" to that thread somehow, so that other users could find that thread when searching for "When does LASSO fail?"

Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: I could ask a question "When does LASSO fail?" and mark it as a duplicate of the other one, but I guess this is not the best way. I could add a nonsense answer to the other thread including the phrase "When does LASSO fail" to make it searchable, but that does not seem like a good idea either.

Comment: This is such a good idea you ought to consider (re-)proposing it on the [SE meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21285).

Comment: @whuber, I trust your experience on meta, so I will follow your suggestion. Oh, but the thread you link to covers that already...

Comment: OK, I guess just posting a new question and marking it as duplicate is acceptable, judging by [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) (scroll towards the end, there is an explicit citation of relevance to this question).